# iOS 8 How to get Serialnumber

Tags: ios, ios8

In our applications the user autentications is based on the serial number.It seems that in ios 8 it is not possible to get the serialnumber.Is any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create a unique random id to identify the device, it will not change unless and until you reset the device. If you want to implement this i can provide the code.

Comment: Basically we place all the unique identifiers in the server before installing the application.And when user install the application we send unique id from device to server to autenticate

Comment: Yes so you have to call the api which will return the id from the server and you store it in the device.

Comment: This application should work for some iPads only of unqiue id's in the server

Comment: So only those ipad will be able to install the apps?

Comment: Before installing the application need to get all the unique identifiers and place it server. Then only that paticular device will be able to install the application

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get the id before installing. Sorry i have no idea about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple deprecated access to a unique-per-device UUID (known as `uniqueIdentifier` as of iOS 6. As of iOS 7, they also blocked access to MAC querying the address, and other sorts of unique identifiers. Sometime between iOS 6 and today, they started rejecting any application that accesses this property.

There are two replacement APIs that might help: on `UIDevice`, there is `identifierForVendor`, that is consistent **across your apps**. And there is also an entire framework, `AdSupport`, who's job is to provide an identifier that can be used for advertising networks. This identifier has the limitation of **people can change it whenever they want**, so you cannot rely on it being consistent across multiple launches.

The hint Apple is trying to pass on here is "you cannot consistently, uniquely identify people per device across multiple apps that are not your own".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to zadr excellent explanation I would like to not iCloud as another possible solution:

Simply store a value (as file or key-value) in iCloud. Only disadvantage of this approach is, that you will have to add the iCloud entitlement to your app if your app does not use iCloud yet. On the other hand there are some advantages

- Very little / none additional effort necessary if your app already uses iCloud
- No additional Frameworsk like `AdSupport` necessary
- The saved value will be consistent between devices and app re-install
- More than one app can share the ID by using the same iCloud (ubiquity container)

Of course in some cases this might be a little overdone but in other this can be a handy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using uniqueIdentifier as suggested above but saving in keychain. This way its reliably available to you all the time, and can be used to track the user.